# Using autofixture in my data integration tests to create proxies

Tags: integration-testing, autofixture

I'm trying to write a suite of database integration tests for my domain which uses Entity Framework.  I would prefer to autofixture objects in some scenarios. My ideal syntax would be something like

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void AutofixtureMyEntityEntity()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    fixture.Customize<MyEntity>(
      c => c.FromFactory<MyDbContext>(ctx => ctx.Set<MyEntity>().Create()));

    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        fixture.Inject(context);
        var entity = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyEntity>();
        context.Set<MyEntity>().Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

[TestMethod]    
[ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
public void AutoFixtureMyEntityEntityWithoutInjection()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    fixture.Customize<MyEntity>(
       c => c.FromFactory<MyDbContext>(ctx => ctx.Set<MyEntity>().Create()));

    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var entity = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyEntity>();
        context.Set<MyEntity>().Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Obviously, that isn't working since `CreateAnonymous()` isn't expecting the input parameter for the factory. I can only assume that i have a flawed understanding of what `FromFactory()` provides. Although the comment reads,

```
/// Specifies that a specimen should be created in a particular way, using a single input
/// parameter for the factory.
```

After reading [ploehs blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/19/ConstructorStrategiesForAutoFixture.aspx), I'm slightly more confused on how these pieces interact with each other.

The instance of `MyDbContext` during factory invocation is not the instance I passed to `Inject()`

Comment: You can use `fixture.Inject( context)` which will mean that any requirement for a Context will use that instance. Would that work? (To be honest your question is quite muddled - you have loads of proposed approaches and its good to know you've tried, but the single problem you have isnt 100% clear to me)

Comment: Ruben, I tried to tighten up the example. Messed around with Inject quite a bit without any luck, i'm trying to supply an instance to the factory potentially before each call to create anonymous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize<MyEntity>(c => c
    .FromFactory<MyDbContext, MyEntity>(ctx => ctx.Set<MyEntity>.Create()));

using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    fixture.Inject(context);
    var item = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyEntity>();
    context.Set<MyEntity>().Add(item);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried to compile this...

---

FWIW, if you were using xUnit.net with AutoFixture, you could reduce the test to something like:

```
[Theory, MyAutoData]
public void TheTest([Frozen]MyDbContext context, MyEntity item)
{
    context.Set<MyEntity>().Add(item);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I needed to customize then provide the injection, a couple extension methods will provide a very flexible tools to write integration tests against my domain. Might add some logic to fixture against any `DataAnnotations ` in the future.

Comment: I added a teaser about making it even simpler.