# AutoFixture EF entity constraints

Tags: entity-framework, edmx, autofixture

Is it possbile to configure AutoFixture so that it adheres the entity constraints [from the EDMX file]?

E.g. Consider a snippet from the CSDL section of my EDMX file:

```
<EntityType Name="RndtAd">
...
<Property Name="AD" Type="Decimal" Precision="12" Scale="0" Nullable="false" />
<Property Name="USERNAME" Type="String" MaxLength="255" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
<Property Name="VERSION" Type="Decimal" Precision="12" Scale="4" Nullable="false" />
<Property Name="EFFECTIVE_FROM" Type="DateTime" Precision="3" />
<Property Name="EFFECTIVE_FROM_TZ" Type="DateTime" Precision="7" />
<Property Name="EFFECTIVE_TILL" Type="DateTime" Precision="3" />
<Property Name="EFFECTIVE_TILL_TZ" Type="DateTime" Precision="7" />
<Property Name="IS_TEMPLATE" Type="String" MaxLength="1" FixedLength="true" Unicode="false" />
<Property Name="IS_USER" Type="String" MaxLength="1" FixedLength="true" Unicode="false" />
<Property Name="STRUCT_CREATED" Type="String" MaxLength="1" FixedLength="true" Unicode="false" />
<Property Name="AD_TP" Type="String" MaxLength="20" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
<Property Name="PERSON" Type="String" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
<Property Name="TITLE" Type="String" MaxLength="20" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
<Property Name="FUNCTION_NAME" Type="String" MaxLength="20" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
<Property Name="COMPANY" Type="String" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
<Property Name="STREET" Type="String" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
...
```

What I would like if `fixture.Create<RndtAd>()` generated randomly an entity where all the previous constraints are satisfied.

What options do I have? All suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT.** I'm not bound to AutoFixture. If there is another tool which does the job, I'm ok with that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoFixture has no built-in support for Entity Framework, but during the last couple of years, several people have fought their own battles to integrate the two.

Here's what a Google search turned up for me:

- [Autofixture and Moq to test Entity Framework project](http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/04/autofixture-and-moq-to-test-entity-framework-project)
- [AutoFixture.AutoEntityFramework](https://github.com/alexfoxgill/AutoFixture.AutoEntityFramework)
- [Creating a domain model without circular references in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19840537/126014)
- [Using autofixture in my data integration tests to create proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14391146/126014)
- [How to mockup Entity Framework 6 With Moq & Autofixture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19328224/126014)

Perhaps you can find some inspiration by looking some of those resources over.

Answer (score 2):

*As-is*, AutoFixture can't be customized through `.EDMX` files.