# AutoFixture code based EF entity constraints

Tags: entity-framework, integration-testing, autofixture

Is Autofixture capable of creating an entity depending upon the mapping configuration done using EF fluent API? I am looking more specifically where a string has a certain length been configured but Autofixutre is generating string with longer length.

-- Updated question --
Let's take an example of a *User* entity with *UserName* property whose length is fixed to 8 character. The configuration of *UserName* Property is done using EF Fluent API, something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(t => t.UserName).HasMaxLength(8);
```

Now when I instantiate User entity using Autofixture it gives me a string of *UserName* with longer than 8. This will trigger an exception while trying to save this entity into db. There are lot of properties with different configuration, which is preventing me to take the full benefit of using Autofixture.

Comment: How is the length specified in code? Can you provide a small sample?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24972120/126014

Comment: MarkSeemann: The question is related to the one you referred, but it’s not exactly the same.
@NikosBaxevanis: I have updated my question to elaborate the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoFixture doesn't know anything about your ORM. So there is no built-in support for EF configuration. It does indeed support a bit of [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) attributes.

I guess only 3 of them are supported by AutoFixture:

- StringLengthAttribute
- RegularExpressionAttribute
- RangeAttribute

So for you particular example you could add `[StringLength]` to your UserName property  instead of using Fluent API.

For more support you would need an extension that can read your EF configuration and configure AutoFixture with EF constraints. There were some efforts in this direction but seems it's harder than it sounds.

Look here - https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/162

Comment: even though your answer doesn't answer the question it points to the correct direction (_some effort done but seem harder than it sounds_)